# NodeJs: Chrome inspector can map source but unable to debug on original source

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I have attached chrome inspector to a NodeJS process and see that Chrome can detect the running built source code ( /dist folder ) and also correctly mapped the source code ( /src folder ) to the built source code

However, Whenever I put a debug point in the original source code (/src) , the debugging point is set to the correct line in the built (/dist) version instead and I can only debug the with the built version but not the original source code

The situation can be seen in the picture
Did I do something wrong?
This is a follow up to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119801/how-to-debug-built-production-nodejs) which involve VS Code Debugger, in the case of VS Code, they can not even detect the original source or sourcemap!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to be buggy async sourcemap from babel. We had to upgrade @babel/core from version 7.9.0 to 7.13 and add these 2 parts also into .babelrc

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "retainLines": true,
```